# Jquery not working in ASP.net DIV just flickers and will be stuck in its position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I am new to JQuery and I have a code in asp.net when ever i click linkbuttons that does not change anything... the div will flickers and div wont be changing its direction. I want to move the DIV left or right by 200px but i tried many but dint happened......please any suggestions

```
<asp:Content ID="ID" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#rightScroll").click(function () {
      $(".lyr1").animate({ "left": "+=150px" }, "slow");
});

$("#leftScroll").click(function () {
    $(".lyr1").animate({ "left": "-=150px" }, "slow");
});
});
</script>
<div>
<asp:LinkButton ID="rightScroll" Text="Previous" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<div id="wn" class="wn">
<div id="lyr1" class="lyr1"> 
<ul id="horiz">
<li  style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; padding-top:2px; padding-bottom:2px;'>                      <asp:Button ID="btn1" Text="click" runat="server"/>  </li>

<li style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; padding-top:2px; padding-bottom:2px;'>         <asp:Image ID="this" ImageUrl="~\img\ajax-loader1.gif" Width="100" Height="100"  runat="server" /></li>
 <li style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; padding-top:2px; padding-bottom:2px;'>     <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~\img\banner.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" runat="server"   /></li>
 <li  style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; padding-top:2px; padding-  bottom:2px;'>   <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="~\img\blackBoard.jpg" Width="100"    Height="100" runat="server" /></li>
 <li  style='padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; padding-top:2px; padding- bottom:2px;'>   <asp:Image ID="Image3" ImageUrl="~\img\ajax-loader1.gif" Width="100"   Height="100" runat="server" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<asp:LinkButton ID="leftScroll" Text="Next" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>             
</asp:Content>
```

AND CSS

```
.wn
{
position: relative; /* scroll area div must be positioned */
width: 670px;
height: 120px; /* width and height required. adjust to suit  */
overflow: hidden; /* required! */
}

.lyr1
{
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#leftScroll,
#rightScroll{
padding:10px 30px;
background-color:red;
position:relative;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/SqKc8/

Comment: hello sir thank you for the help.....I wanted to make it circular..when i click it will go out of the Div size. I need to loop back again... is there any option